# when i send a push notification while my app is running,my app crashes

Tags: android

When i send a push notification **while my app is running,my app crashes** (via fire base console), but works just fine when my app is closed or running in the background.

Comment: how are you sending & receiving push notification

Comment: firebase console>notifications>send new message

Comment: I used Postman but i could not or rather i do not know how to send notifications to multiple devices, any help in this aspect? code segment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem is Getting in

> class which is extends FirebaseMessagingService

**FirebaseMessagingService** this class is use to catch push notification.

so when your application is open you need to just check your code in

> public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)

Check your code in this method.

**As per your second question when your application is closed or in background at the time OnMessageReceived() method is not handling a event of Push Notification**

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 main ways of getting a push notification from fire base

1) When application is in foreground (application is running or opened)

2) When application is in background  (application is not running or closed)

In  first case if you send push notification from fire base console the notification message and custom data payload is received in 
**public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)**
In short when application is in foreground onMessageReceived method will trigger always , notification data must be handled inside this method.

In second case if u send push notification from fire base console the notification message is received in **system tray** 
and you can receive the data payload in the **bundle extras** of the launcher activity of your application.